# Any way to avoid nesting usings when opening a SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader

Not a big deal but for neatness sake is there any way to "create and open" a `SqlConnection`?

I naively wrote this code:

```
using (var strConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnection))
using (var strCommand = new SqlCommand(query, strConnection))
using (var reader = strCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    ...
}
```

Which of course fails on line 3 because the connection isn't open.
Is there a neat way to avoid that nesting that opening the connection introduces?

```
using (var strConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnection))
{
    strConnection.Open();
    using (var strCommand = new SqlCommand(query, strConnection))
    using (var reader = strCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the connection just for the one command? Maybe you should keep the connection open for a longer time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, my idea is an Extension-Method for `SqlConnection`.

Check this:

```
public static class SqlExtensions {
    public static SqlConnection OpenAndReturn(this SqlConnection con) {
        try {
            con.Open();
            return con;
        } catch {
            if(con != null)
                con.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using(var strConnection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION").OpenAndReturn()) 
using(var strCommand = new SqlCommand("QUERY", strConnection))
using(var reader = strCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    //...       
}
```

Comment: Using this approach isn't really recommended: if an exception occurs in `OpenAndReturn` then the connection won't be disposed. ie, In this case the `using` block starts protecting the object when it's returned from `OpenAndReturn`, not when it's created by `new SqlConnection(...)`. (Of course, you could beef up the extension method with it's own `try...catch...Dispose` logic to compensate for this.)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that:

```
class SqlHelper : IDisposable
{
    public SqlHelper(string connectionString, string query) { ... }

    public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public SqlCommand Command { get; set; }

    // SQL querying logic here
    public void Execute() { ... }

    /** IDisposable implementation **/
}
```

and in your code

```
using (SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper(sourceConnection, query)) 
{
    var reader = sql.Execute();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @svick That's a good point, maybe you can pass the block in the `using` as a delegate so the reader can be disposed from within the helper.